# How to Translate "10:10" to epoch format

Tags: c++, qt

I am parsing a .json and plotting it using qt custom plot but for the x axis I need to translate "10:10" to secSinceEpoch, does anyone know the easiest way about going about this? I also have the date in ISODate format(2020-05-26) so I need to basically do the "date: 2020-05-26" + "minute: 10:10" to get the correct x axis value for that point correct? I am just stuck on figuring out how to get the epoch time of "10:10"

For some reason when i output the year after translating 2020-05-26 it says 1950, any idea why that is too?

Here is my current code

```
            time.push_back(chartData[i]["date"].asString());
            minute.push_back(chartData[i]["minute"].asString());
            timeInEpoch.push_back(QDateTime::fromString(time[i].c_str(), Qt::ISODate).toSecsSinceEpoch() + QDateTime::fromString(minute[i].c_str(), "hh:mm").toSecsSinceEpoch());
```

Edit: Full Code

```
    //Retrieves json format of data
    Json::Value chartData = IEX::stocks::chartRange(symbolSearchedStd, "5dm");

    //Stores x and y values
    QVector<double> value, timeInEpoch;
    QVector<string>time, minute;
    setupLineChart("yyyy, MMM d", 8);

    int  n = chartData.size();

    //Finds max and min for range
    float maxAvg = chartData[0]["average"].asDouble();
    float minAvg = chartData[0]["average"].asDouble();

    //Reads in data from json(historical data 1 day delayed)
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
            value.push_back(chartData[i]["average"].asDouble());
            time.push_back(chartData[i]["date"].asString());
            minute.push_back(chartData[i]["minute"].asString());
            timeInEpoch.push_back(QDateTime::fromString(time[i].c_str(), Qt::ISODate).toSecsSinceEpoch() + QDateTime::fromString(minute[i].c_str(), "hh:mm").toSecsSinceEpoch());


            if((value[i] == 0) && (i != n - 1))
            {
                value[i] = value[i-1];
            }

            if(value[i] > maxAvg)
            {
                maxAvg = value[i];
            }

            else if(value[i] < minAvg)
            {
                minAvg = value[i];
            }
    }

    stockData(value[n-1], value[n-2]);

    //Assigns data to graph
    ui->stockGraph->graph(0)->setData(timeInEpoch, value);
```

Comment: Why not create a single string containing both the date and the time, for example `"2020-05-26 10:10"` and use one of the many time-parsing functions to get the time-stamp for it?

Comment: Your QDateTime needs a date. Not just a time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So set a string up to combine the both because my parser parses minute and date seperately, i will edit this post showing the full code.

Comment: Absl time is nice library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can parse date and time separately:

```
const char * date = "2020-05-26";
const char * time = "10:10";

auto d = QDate::fromString(date, Qt::ISODate);
auto t = QTime::fromString(time, "hh:mm");

auto dt = QDateTime(d, t);

qDebug() << "d = " << d << " t = " << t << " dt = " << dt << " secs = " << dt.toSecsSinceEpoch();

//d =  QDate("2020-05-26")  t =  QTime("10:10:00.000")  dt =  QDateTime(2020-05-26 10:10:00.000 +07 Qt::LocalTime)  secs =  1590462600
```